# Cannot launch native blackberry BB10 browser as a separate session

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry-webworks

This >button< code is what I've been using to open a site in a separate browser window:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/railsafety/rules-tco93.htm','_blank')">CROR</button>
```

The >button< code works as expected when I'm using Eclipse/PhoneGap to develop my BlackBerry Z10 app. Tap on the button and the site opens in a separate window.

I'm in the process of switching to BlackBerry's WebWorks platform. When that same code is executed the browser window opens over top of my app. How do I get it to open in it's own window?

I've been through other examples I found on stackoverflow but they seem to deal with older Blackberry OS's and devices.

I've also looked at BlackBerry's doc's and they seem to be contradictory (I guess the platform is so new that it's evolving very quickly).

Thanks 
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a pretty good sample for the BlackBerry WebWorks GitHub repo. which will show you exactly how to do this. Essentially you can do it a couple of ways.

**JavaScript**

```
  // top
  var link = document.getElementById('vTop');
  link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    childWindow = window.open('http://developer.blackberry.com', '_top');
  });
```

**Inline**

```
<a href="http://developer.blackberry.com" target="_top">Click Me</a>
```

Note that in WebWorks you'll want to 'white-list' the domain you're attempting to access as well.  Check out the full sample here: [BB10-WebWorks-Samples/ChildBrowser](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/childBrowser)

Comment: I'll download your sample and give it a try. The "window.open" instruction you're using is similar to what I tried. Except I used '_blank' instead of '_top' because I wanted the new window to be in a separate webview. I wonder if the '_blank' option is no longer acceptable?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. Using FireFox (for example) on my desktop system, when I create a weblink using "_blank" a completely separate browser window (or tab) opens. That way I can easily switch between viewing my page and the new site. I guess what I'd like to do in this case is open the new site as a separate entity, so the user can flip between my app and the web resource that's been accessed. Is that possible using webworks?

Comment: Some additional info. I just tried a quick and dirty app using eclipse/phonegap and specifying "_blank" does open the new window as a completely separate entity. Seems like it might be problem with WebWorks. I'll file a report on BB Dev site.